# Chi-Square transformation on a partially unknown matrix

Tags: r, data-transformation

This question is a follow up to 
[Hellinger transformation with relative data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151120/hellinger-transformation-with-relative-data).
I want to chi-square-transform my species abundance table, which represents only a fraction of the total species table. I know the total count for each row (the row sums), but nothing else; the missing columns are unknown to me.
Is it still possible to perform the chi square transformation? According to [the vegan vignette on the R function decostand](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan/html/decostand.html) i need to know the column, row, and matrix sums.
If so, what could a possible function in R look like?
Thank you.

Comment: What's a " chi-square-transform"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chi square transformation is a transformation of a data matrix $Y \rightarrow Y^{\prime}$ such that when one computes the Euclidean distance of $Y^{\prime}$ the resulting dissimilarity matrix represents chi-square distances *in the original* data $Y$.

The transformation is

$$y^{\prime}_{ij} = \sqrt{y_{..}} \left ( \frac{y_{ij}}{y_{i.} \sqrt{y_{.j}}} \right )$$

where $y^{\prime}_{ij}$ is the chi-square transformed data for species $j$ in the $i$th sample/row, $y_{..}$ is the grand total of the matrix (your "matrix sum"), $y_{i.}$ is the row sum for the $i$th row, and $y_{.j}$ is the column sum for the $j$th species.

Mathematically there is nothing stopping you from computing this using the grand total and row and column sums of the subset of data you have available. If this makes sense for your data/application then I don't know enough detail about that to answer the question.

Conceptually, if you are willing to consider essentially relative composition in terms of *relative to the subset of species/variables you have* then it is probably OK. If it would seem odd to think of relative composition of the community based only on a subset of the species then perhaps you shouldn't do this.

I should add, that while the documentation for `decostand()` in **vegan** talks about the row and column sums and grand total, it will actually compute these from the data supplied to `decostand()` - there isn't a mechanism for you to supply these even if you did know them.

Comment: Thank you again. Seeing that the term includes yij/yi (what i would call relative abundances), i figure that using relative data as input for a CCA is redundant, correct?

Comment: Would it be feasible to include a dummy OTU (containing ALL remaining signals in a row), perform the transformation on that matrix, and for CCA go back to the partial matrix? I am also considering a single bacterial phylum in a general dataset.  I did no OTU clustering in for the other phyla, i just know how many signals remain in those phyla. Thank you!

Comment: CCA is not redundant on those data; the two square root terms are important weightings & even the analysis itself is a weighted linear model which is why you can't do a chi-square transformation followed by RDA and get exactly the same results as CCA. The RDA version is an unweighted analysis.

Comment: As for the other question; I'd work out first what your OTUs represent, can you consider them the community of interest? As a limnologist, I might go an look at all species of zooplankton I can find in my samples, but what about the algae or other inverts, etc? I can rightly consider the zooplankton in isolation for the purposes of the analysis. Can you consider your OTUs that you have data for in that or a similar way?

Comment: 1. Sorry for being not clear enough. I am not referring to the CCA as being redundant. I was questioning if my approach of passing relative data to CCA is flawed because data relativizing to row.sums is part of the data transformation CCA is doing anyway. I may just have a try with raw and relative data, and see whats going on.

Comment: 2. You are right, but the OTU clustering is only available for that one phylum. For the other phyla, i just have read counts by a taxonomic classifier. At the moment this cannot be changed.

Comment: Re 2. Right; so it sounds like it would be OK to just consider the selection of OTUs you do have as the "community" you wish to analyse, and take the row/col/total sum from the data (relativised if that is what you are using - i.e apply the *entire* transformation to the data you are using)